# Which tools does jQuery use to compress its source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, google-closure-compiler

Which tools does jQuery use to compress its source code in version 1.6.2?

Comment: I remember it used different minifiers for different versions.  It used YUI Compressor before, also Packer before (but then John Resig wrote a note saying that it is not worth the extra decoding step to use Packer), then briefly (I think 1.6) using Closure Compiler (simple mode), then now moved to Uglify I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/). Previously (until 1.4) they used [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/).

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile#L9

Comment: Thanks. jQuery use UglifyJS starting from 1.5

Comment: till 1.4: Used packer. From 1.4.2: Switched to Google Closure compiler. From 1.5: Switched to UglifyJS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I find this ([minifyjavascript.com](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/)) useful, dunno if it helps.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that your first name is the same as the author of UglifyJS's name?

Comment: @katspaugh: If it were not, I'm sure he wouldn't be posting about a competing tool. :) Not only do the two gentlemen have different last names, but the first is rather common. So your comment is a bit odd.

Comment: How common is it among international (mostly anglophone) audience? To me it seems rather rare and coincidence peculiar. Not implying anything else.

Comment: @katspaugh: Anglophone is not the same as Western. As it happens, ["Mihai" is the Romanian form of "Michael"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihai_%28name%29), which I imagine is quite common no matter where you go.

Comment: wow, nice that I got a - on my very first answer here... and secondly I never heard of uglifyjs till now. and third what's wrong with my name?

Comment: @MihaiIonescu Well I assume it was because you didn't try to answer the question. However as the down voter didn't specify the reason and you are new, I'll give you a +1 for at least providing an alternative minifier. Please put a little more effort into your next answer though.